# in vim accidentally enter :w1 instead of :wq

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

very often I accidently enter :w1 in vim and not :wq. In that case a file with the name 1 is created.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: A way to prevent you entering the wrong command? I guess you'll eventually just learn to not do that. You don't want to remap

Comment: perhaps use `:x` can save you?

Comment: `:cnoremap w1 wq`

Comment: Change your habit by using `ZZ` instead of `:wq`.

Answer (score 1):

As [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) commented you can create a command line abbreviation:

```
:cnoreab w1 wq
```

You can also exit using <kbd>ZZ</kbd>:

```
ZZ          Write current file, if modified, and close the current
            window (same as ":x").
            If there are several windows for the current file,
            only the current window is closed.
```

You can also consider the current buffer as if it was a scratch buffer and discar everything:

```
ZQ          Quit without checking for changes (same as ":q!").
```